# HotPlug my USB mouse

Tags: mouse, usb

Whenever I try to plug in my optical mouse after my Ubuntu 10.04 has booted, the OS doesn't seem to Hotplug my mouse. For using the mouse I would need to reboot the OS. Is there any script which can activate my mouse?

The output of lsusb command is

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Hama Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN) Interface [Integrated Module]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0001 DigitalPersona, Inc Fingeprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:09b8 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of my syslog:

```
Oct 14 15:00:08 avi-laptop kernel: [15966.380131] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
Oct 14 15:00:08 avi-laptop kernel: [15966.554437] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this bug report, it contains some workarounds as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/564459

Answer (score 2):

It should work out of the box… i think you should report this as a bug on launchpad.net.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, the mouse should be detected automatically.

Can you run

```
udevadm monitor
```

in a terminal and see what gets printed when you plug in your mouse?  I get a bunch of events:

```
KERNEL[1287101516.932598] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1 (usb)
KERNEL[1287101516.937554] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1287101516.937637] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0003 (hid)
KERNEL[1287101516.941362] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38 (input)
KERNEL[1287101516.941765] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38/mouse2 (input)
KERNEL[1287101516.941827] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38/event8 (input)
KERNEL[1287101516.942005] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0003/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
KERNEL[1287101516.942317] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1287101516.942588] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0004 (hid)
UDEV  [1287101516.943166] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1287101516.949212] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1287101516.949292] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0004 (hid)
UDEV  [1287101516.950697] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1287101516.955641] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/input/input39 (input)
UDEV  [1287101516.957342] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0003 (hid)
UDEV  [1287101516.958723] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/0003:046D:C526.0003/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
KERNEL[1287101516.961049] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/input/input39/event9 (input)
KERNEL[1287101516.961188] add      /class/usb (class)
UDEV  [1287101516.962059] add      /class/usb (class)
UDEV  [1287101516.963646] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38 (input)
KERNEL[1287101516.965077] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/usb/hiddev0 (usb)
UDEV  [1287101516.966175] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/usb/hiddev0 (usb)
KERNEL[1287101516.966837] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0004/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1287101516.967578] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/0003:046D:C526.0004/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [1287101516.973294] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/input/input39 (input)
UDEV  [1287101516.988644] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38/mouse2 (input)
UDEV  [1287101517.012808] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.1/input/input39/event9 (input)
UDEV  [1287101517.025623] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/input/input38/event8 (input)
```

By comparing what you see to this it might be possible to determine which piece of the infrastructure is dropping the ball.